# Typo3 6.0: Install Tool Error Message

Tags: typo3, php-5.4

In conjunction with the failed installation of an extension (yag), the install tool is no longer available with the following error message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class '\\tx_install_session' not found in /var/typo3_src-6.0.2/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php on line 4158
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

---

Ok, I'm one step further.

Assuming the backend login works, it helps to clear the cache via the flash button.

Which leads me to the question: Is there a way to do this in the shell in case the BE login is broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove/comment the bad extension in the `LocalConfiguration.php` file and then remove content of `/typo3temp/Cache/` directory.

It will allow you restore to the state before the malformed installation.